# Can view Social Media buttons only in the private mode - why?

Tags: widgets

I can view and click all the Social Media buttons: Twitter, Pinterest, Google and more plus the Like button in the footer but only when I am in a private browsing.  If I browse as usual (not private) then I don't see them at all. I used to be able to view them in any mode.  I'm puzzled

Can someone please explain me this phenomenon.  Thanks

I am in the U.S.  I just had all or most of them installed as Widgets. Am not doing Plugins at the moment.

Furthermore I wasn't allowed to post the tags for lack of reputation.  Time to take off from WordPress that's what I am thinking.

Comment: Try to clear your browser cache, may be its a reason for this

Comment: In private mode, your adblocker is probably disabled.

Comment: Where did you get these buttons from? If you "_don't do plugins_", there should be some code responsible for the buttons.

Comment: Like fuxia said, I bet its your ad blocker.  Disable it for your site.